# Contacts Crashes when changing picture

Tags: contacts, crashes, lenovo

I recently bought a Lenovo a 6000+ from flip-kart. 
Now whenever I try to change a contact's Picture in Contacts, It crashes. I can select the picture and it changes. But when I press save, the phone becomes irresponsive and then gives an error message saying that

> "Contact Manager isn't responding. Do you want to wait?"

Then I have to kill it. Waiting doesn't do any good. 
PS: I have changed the images before.This started this week only.
Thanks in advance.
Cleaned data and cache, used very low res pictures etc, didn't work though.

Comment: Sync all contacts to Google and just start off again with Contacts app. To do this **Clear data and cache** for the Contacts app and Sync contacts using Google account.

Comment: @MANI,  Sorry, Should have specified in the question. I have done that. Twice.